# How to organise multiple ActivityHandler classes in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, asp.net-core-3.1

I am developing my first bot using the MS Bot Framework and although I understand the basics, I am a bit clueless as to how to organize my code. For eg. I am planning to have

- notifier
- welcome prompt
- very basic help response

I am using the Core template in Visual Studio and it comes with a `Bots` folder which has classes ending with `Bot`. Looking at some samples, it seemed to me that the bot handling logic needs to sit here. So, I decided to have 3 classes, all extending from `ActivityHandler` each doing one of the above tasks. Say I have 3 classes,

```
public class MyNotifierBot: ActivityHandler
{
    // Constructor and overrides
}

public class WelcomeBot: ActivityHandler
{
    // Constructor and overrides
}

public class ResponseBot: ActivityHandler
{
    // Constructor and overrides
}
```

The first problem is that if I register all 3 classes as `services.AddTransient<IBot, MyNotifierBot>()` etc, I can only get the last registered bot in my controllers. Sure I can get a collection of the implementations in the controller and figure out the right one to use using reflection, it just feels wrong.

My question is, if this pattern is wrong and I should have a single class which extends from `ActivityHandler` and write my logic in seperate services. Or is there a better approach to this.

Edit: After thinking about this I am now wondering the existance of the `Bots` folder in the first place. If I am not meant to create multiple `ActivityHandler` subclasses for doing different things then what exactly is this structure for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActivityHandler` implements `IBot`, so it can be thought of like a bot. Having multiple activity handlers would be like having multiple bots. Activity handlers are already designed to route different activity types to different code, so if routing is your concern then you only need one activity handler.

I presume your notifier is for [proactive messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message). Rather than having a separate activity handler for it, what normally works is to have a separate endpoint, which is usually [`api/notify`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Controllers/NotifyController.cs#L17) (as opposed to `api/messages`). You can still have a separate activity handler for that if you want, or not even use an activity handler for that case (like in the sample). Note that different channels may have special considerations for proactive messages, but that's outside the scope of your question.

[Welcome messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message) are very easy with activity handlers. You can just use `OnMembersAddedAsync` in your one activity handler, and there's no need for a whole separate activity handler. Welcome messages are also channel-specific because they rely on conversation update activities, and not every channel has a well-defined way to know when a conversation starts before the user says anything. Here's a [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event) for if you're using Web Chat.

If you want multiple implementations of the same interface in your dependency injection then you'll need to identify them by the implementation rather than the interface, but keep in mind that you don't need to put them in dependency injection at all.